# Calculate area, circumference e.t.c of circle for different units of diameter and displaying significant digits after decimal point desired by user

Tags: javascript, html

//I want the code to display properties like area and circumference of a circle as soon as i change the units from the drop down and also to display desired significant digits after decimal desired by user.....please don't mind my code only a novice trying to get grip of the language.....

```
<html>

<select name="rd" id="rd">

<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    document.write("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function computeunit() {
     //obtain user input
     var dia = Number(document.getElementById("dia").value);

     var diaunits = document.getElementById("diaunits").value;
     var rn = document.getElementById("rd").value;

     if (diaunits == "meter") dia /= 1.00;
     if (diaunits == "inches") dia /= 39.3700787;
     if (diaunits == "feet") dia /= 3.28084;
     if (diaunits == "yard") dia /= 1.09361;
     if (diaunits == "cm") dia /= 100;
     if (diaunits == "mm") dia /= 1000;

     var circumf = dia * Math.PI;

     document.getElementById("txtcircumf").innerHTML = circumf;

     var ar = (diaN / 2) * (diaN / 2) * Math.PI;

     document.getElementsById("txtarea").innerHTML = ar;

     var rs = new Number(circumf); // don't know how to include area
     var nrs = rs.toFixed(rn);

     document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = nrs;
 }
</script>

<pre>

<body>

<p>Enter your diameter: <input type="text" id="diaunits"/>
    <select type="multiple" id="diaunits">
        <option value="metres" selected="selected">metres</option>
        <option value="inches">inches</option>
        <option value="feet">feet</option>
        <option value="yard">yard</option>
        <option value="centimeter">centimeter</option>
        <option value="millimeter">millimeter</option>
    </select>
    </p>
Circumference: <input type="text" id="txtcircumf" />    
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="computeunit();"/></br>    

Area: <input type="text"  id="txtarea" />
      <input type ="button" value="area" onclick="computeunit();"/></br>

</body>
</pre>

<html>
```

Comment: What's the question? In what way does the code you show not work?

Comment: Also, in future questions please make more of an effort to tidy up your code before dumping it in your question - adopt a consistent indenting style, or at worst run your JS through [jspretty.com](http://jspretty.com) before including it.

Comment: well you should be able to change the units of diameter and the area should change upon selecting the units from drop down and also the user should be able to choose the   number of decimal digits

Comment: So the question is "How do I call a function in response to the user changing a drop-down value or an input value?"

Comment: yup i should be able to the function upon changing the value from drop down.....plz don't mind my code have just started 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

We used to put an `onchange` handler as an attribute of the `select`. Now it may be trendy to attach it using JavaScript, but it's the same effect.

Comment: i tried that but doesn't seems to make any change.....is there any other change that i can make to do this running somehow